# How to load the scripts in the wordpress admin in submenu pages only?

Tags: wordpress, function

I am trying to load the script in one my custom made submenu pages in wordpress admin, it works well for the main menu pages like:

> http://www.mydomain.com/wp/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=product

but not for a submenu page:

> http://www.mydomain.com/wp/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=product&page=my-products

```
function pw_load_scripts($hook) {
if( $hook != 'edit.php' ) // load in edit page only
    return;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

Put this condition:

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

$postData = query_posts('category_name='.$slug.'&post_status=publish,future&paged='.$paged);

if($postData[0]->slug == 'page slug name'){
    <script> </script>
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by this?

Comment: add particular JS in particular page, thats what you want, here you can specify with their SLUG name.

Comment: Alright, i was actually looking for a way to check the $hook against the url parameters.